# How to uninstall TeamViewer, if there is no option for doing so?

Tags: windows, uninstall, teamviewer, windows-10-v1909

**tl;dr** *"Something" installed a TeamViewer on my brand new computer. How to get rid of it? There's no corresponding option in "Add/Remove Programs" list and there is neither "TeamViewer" group nor "Uninstall TeamViever" option in Start Menu*.

---

I have just installed a fresh Windows 10 Pro on my old Acer PC. I have logged-in with my Microsoft account and after a few minutes of using it, I found a TeamViever being installed among other applications that I have. **I am 100% positive that I didn't installed this program myself**. Most likely Windows, trying to decide for me, installed it for my after I logged-in with my old, good Microsoft account (if that's possible).

I cannot uninstall this program, because:

- there's no "TeamViewer" group in Start Menu,
- there's no "Uninstall TeamViewer" item in start Menu,
- there's no "TeamViewer" item in Start > Control Panel > Uninstall a program list.

When I hit Start, type `TeamViewer`, right-click it on search results list and select "Uninstall" from context menu, I am redirected to the above list (in Control Panel) where there is no corresponding item.

In the very same way, as above, Skype was installed on the very same computer, Windows 10 and the same Microsoft account -- but on contrary to above situation, when I typed `Skype` in Start Menu and selected "Uninstall" from context menu, Skype was uninstalled without any problems.

How can I get rid of TeamViewer in this scenario?

Comment: @trejder To build on [Ramhound's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1539957/529800), Windows desktop applications are not the same as UWP apps... UWP apps can only be installed via the Microsoft Store or Powershell and must be uninstalled in those two ways. UWP apps will never show in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`, or in the root of `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, as they're installed into parent directory `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, which is a sandboxed location

Comment: @trejder - I simply wrote one answer.  Your original revision of both questions, made it appear, the same underline problem existed.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** *Turned out that this is not a "real" application, but rather Google Chrome extension that (in case of TeamViewer) registers itself as a full-featured application, with shortcuts in Start Menu etc. Removing it from Google Chrome actually solved the problem*

---

There are at least three types of applications in Windows 10:

- regular apps (uninstall via *Control Panel > Add/Remove programs*),
- UWP apps (uninstall via *Settings > Apps and features*),
- [rarest case] Google Chrome's (and other browser's?) extensions that registers itself as full-feature applications.

TeamViewer is a kind of third type. Even though installed through Chrome, it adds its own shortcuts to Start Menu etc.

To get rid of it you must uninstall corresponding extension from Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to c:\program files\ or c:\program files (x86) and look for its installation folder there. (if you can't find it, check the properties of a shortcut that starts the program to determine the folder location) there should be an uninstall.exe
2. use CCleaner, see if it appears in the list of programs to uninstall

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually solves my question, so I can't accept it, but I'll up-vote it, since you gave me inspiration to actually solve the issue. BTW: As far as a remember CCleaner isn't able to uninstall _any_ application or program that you can't uninstall yourself using Control Panel or Settings.

Answer (score -1):

I also couldn't uninstall teamviewer--we were just using the free version and then went with something else.  a few months later I decided to uninstall and it kept telling me a version was open (wasn't).  I deleted all the connections and updated the program, closed it, rebooted and it uninstalled perfectly

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. There the problem was not to have any "uninstall" option, which is apparently not the case for you.