# Stop Windows 10 from installing applications that I am using on another PC

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-v1909

I have just installed a fresh Windows 10 Pro on my old Acer PC. I have logged-in with my Microsoft account and after a few minutes of using it, I found a number of applications installed that I use on my other PCs with the same Microsoft account:

- [TeamViever](https://superuser.com/q/1539881/156554),
- Skype etc.

**I am 100% positive that I didn't installed these apps myself**. Most likely Windows, trying to decide for me, installed it for my after I logged-in with my old, good Microsoft account (if that's possible).

While I managed to get rid of Skype, I [failed uninstalling TeamViewer](https://superuser.com/q/1539881/156554). So, this feature or whatever this is, wastes my time and causes me additional troubles.

How can I stop Windows from installing apps that I have installed on another PC, everywhere I login with my Microsoft account, without my direct consent?

Comment: Well, a literally correct answer to your final question would be "Don't run Windows"... - But that's probaly not, what you're asking for...

Comment: Did you try turning on the metered connection option? It stops background downloading of apps while letting in the important security updates.

Comment: To build on @Ramhound's answer below, Windows desktop applications are not the same as UWP apps... UWP apps can only be installed via the Microsoft Store or Powershell and must be uninstalled in those two ways, or via Settings.  UWP apps will never show in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`, or in the root of `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, as they're installed into parent directory `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, which is a sandboxed location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am 100% positive that I didn't install these apps myself.

TeamViewer is not a default application.  It is never automatically installed unless you have enable a feature like profile synchronization or created a Windows image that has TeamViewer already installed.

**There is something else going on.**  I am going to guess, you have installed the application on another computer that is also linked to your Microsoft Account, and you have profile synchronization enable.

Universal Windows Program (UWP) applications are automatically installed and synchronized.  In order to uninstall TeamViewer, open Settings, and choose the option to uninstall TeamViewer.

[image]

> How can I stop Windows from installing apps that I have installed on another PC, everywhere I login with my Microsoft account, without my direct consent?

**You actually gave consent when you enabled profile syncing.**  If you were to disable synchronization it should prevent the Microsoft Store from automatically installing applications you have installed on another computer.

This is no different than Android or iOS automatically installing applications you used on your old phone.  **Once a UWP application is uninstalled, that particular application, will not be reinstalled on the device unless you do so manually.**

[image]

Comment: You mixed up single answer for my two separate questions. For the first question (here) your answer is perfectly valid. And I am going to accept it, thank you. For the other question your answer is wrong / not working. As you can read in my other question, I don't have TeamViewer neither in Control Panel's Add/Remove programs list and not in Settings > Apps and featured list. I can't uninstall it with the solution you gave here. I'd strongly suggest to not mix two questions in a single answer and to move half of your answer to the other question. If you decide to keep it at all.

Comment: @trejder - It is my belief that this answer is better as a whole, given that the application you wanted to uninstall, was actually a Chrome extension and not a UWP application.  However, my answer also applies to the Skype UWP application, which is the reason it works as a whole.